# getting compile error with sqlite-3.7.6.3 on Linux i686

Tags: linux, sqlite, ubuntu

I have sqlite-3.7.6.3 library. I have to compile this library and make a package. MY system is Linux i686.

The library folder contains some patches, **src** folder and **amalgamation** folder.

I have performed the following steps:

1. I changed directory to src i.e. **cd/sqlite-3.7.6.3/src**.
2. I ran **sudo ./configure**, which worked perfectly fine.
3. I then ran **make**. I am getting error on running make. The error is:

> ./src/shell.c:2668: undefined reference to `sqlite_shell_init_icu'

I have not been able to figure out the problem so far. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: It will help if you provide all the steps that you have taken. Also describe your Ubuntu version and architecture.

Comment: version is Linux i686 . . sqlite-3.7.3 folder contains a /src folder. What I have done, I changed my dir to /src folder.     Then I applied ./config followed by make command

Comment: Edit your question and add those details with an easy to read format, so that people reading this can find them easily.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try:</strike>

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
make
```

From the official site:

> Note that a unix-like development environment, including a recent version of Tcl, is required in order to build from the repository sources. The amalgamation source code files (the "sqlite3.c" and "sqlite3.h" files) are **not contained in the repository**.

Have you done that? [How To Compile SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html)

I highly suspect that the problem lies there. You need to download the amalgamation tarball that is appropriate to your version.

Comment: i have also installed tcl . . .

Comment: Where did you get the source code, I'm looking at the repo and the 3.7.3 tag is missing.

Comment: sorry its 3.7.6.3 release , my mistake                          http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_6_3.html

Comment: I have sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files in amalgamation folder. I have also copied these files in src folder along with shell.c file ! ! I guess that's all needed . . .

Comment: i just downloaded the latest version of sqlite "sqlite-autoconf-3080301". That worked fine with config and make.  Question is what's wrong with 3.7.6.3 version then?

Comment: hi givanse any guidance plz

Comment: It is clear that a library or patch is missing. Re-read the docs and revisit your steps. Try a newer Amalgamation version (patched maybe) with your SQLite version.

Comment: hi, I have been able to solve the issue. When I commented out the following section (can u think of why?):                                                    /* Begin evanm patch. 
  extern int sqlite_shell_init_icu();
  if( !sqlite_shell_init_icu() ){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: warning: couldn't find icudt38.dll; "
                    "queries against ICU FTS tables will fail.\n", argv[0]);
  }
  /* End evanm patch. */